# iPhone Application Should go to Background, then close after a few minutes of inactivity

Tags: iphone, cordova, multitasking

I have an app which when the user clicks the iphone's home button, the application is sent to background. But I want it to be closed after a few minutes of inactivity.  Is this possible?

I have seen UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to YES in my app's Info.plist file, but this closes the app straight away.

Answer (score 3):

In your app delegate, you must implement `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`, calling `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^()]` on `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` and storing the result. The app's code will continue to run in a background.

Then, when you want to close the app, call `endBackgroundTask:` with the task identifier you got from the code above.

If you combine this with UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend, you might get the behaviour you want...